# $http.put is not responding anything in angular.js, node.js Api

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating restful API using Node.js. and consuming API with Angular.
Everything is going perfect. But data is not updating with PUT method.

```
app.put('/contactlist/:id', function(req, res){
    var id=req.params.id; 
    contactModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id:req.params.id},
        {$set:{name:req.body.name, email:req.body.email, number:req.body.number}}, 
        {new:true}, 
        function(err, data){
            res.json(data);
            }
        );
});
```

**angular.js**

```
$scope.update=function(id){
    console.log("id from update button" +id);
    $http.put("/contactlist/" +id, $scope.contactlist).success(function(res){
        console.log(res);
        refreshdata();
    });
}
```

**html**

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contactlist.name" name="name"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contactlist.email" name="email" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contactlist.number" name="number" /></td>
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-Click="addContact()">Add</button>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="update(contactlist._id)">Update</button></td>
  </tr>
```

So, I am trying to update data, its not doing anything. Please have a look at my code and let me know the error

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in any log? Client- or server-side?

Comment: No.... there is nothing in console. Even its not printing `null` or                   `undefined`.  Its just empty space on the  line number of  `console.log(res);` in console.

Comment: Check the Network tab, where you'll be able to see the status of your network request

Comment: Yeah .. In network tab its showing warning `Provisional headers are shown` ... does it make any sense?

Comment: Bro, There is a chance that, Requests are not being completed.. In that case also, you cant see any logs .. brcause logs are printed on request completion... So make sure that callback passed to findandupdate is in correct format